# Project Euler #5 php doubt!

Tags: php, performance, for-loop

[problem euler #5](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=5)

i found the solution but i don't know why this first code is faster (i put 14 in order to try to make more clear the code) the only difference is that i eliminate the for i wrote for a huge if

```
if($num%14==0 && $num%13==0 &&$num%12==0 &&$num%11==0 &&$num%10==0 && $num%9==0 && $num%8==0 && $num%7==0 && $num%6==0 && $num%5==0 && $num%4==0 && $num%3==0 && $num%2==0 && $num%1==0){
    $notFound=0;
}
```

why is this second code hugely more slow than the first one? With the *for* it suppose to be faster. is the same in another languages???

```
$notFound=0;
for ( $i=14; $i>=2 && notFound==0; $i--){
    if($num%$i!=0){
        $notFound=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry am going to fix the post

Comment: retagged "euler5" to "project-euler"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code sample is simply performing more operations than the first, so I'd expect it to be slower.  In this situation, you'd find that whilst offering poorer performance, a `for` loop offers significantly better readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

`for ( $i=14; $i>=2 && notFound==0; $i--){`

should be

`for ( $i=14; $i>=2 && $notFound==0; $i--){`

Answer (score 2):

I would go from the smallest to the largest number. Because if a number is divisible by 14 it is also divisible by 2.

```
$notFound = 0;
for ($i=2; $i<=14; $i++) {
    if ($num % $i !== 0) {
        $notFound = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

By doing this you can exclude the numbers as early as possible.

Comment: Well it can cut both ways...it might pass the test for the smaller  numbers (2, 3, etc.) only to fail the test for the bigger ones. if you can isolate only the prime factors from 2 to 14 and test for divisibility with only those, then it can probably be a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the interpreter overhead with PHP (with it having to parse and execute the for loop).